# como fazer os itens do banco de dados aparecerem no meu Dropdown itens no HTML?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql

ERRO ao tentar
Estou usando C#, .NET, PostgreSQL, RazorPages, e Bootstrap
Tenho um cadastro de escolas que leva ate a table Escolas.
e outro de Alunos, que leva pra table Alunos.
Na aba de cadastro de alunos, preciso colocar um dropdown, que os itens dele, sejam o nome das escolas, sempre se atualizando, conforme o banco vai crescendo, sem precisar de atualização.
Como posso fazer? através de uma API?
ou no CSHTML ja consigo?
Não sei se deveria usar a Tag 'table', mas pensei assim para puxar talvez do Postgresql.
Ja tenho toda a conexão, todo o CRUD, mas não consigo linkar ambos

[Print Organização](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwimB.png)

```
<h1> Cadastros </h1>

<h4> Alunos </h4>
<div class="dropdown">
     <button class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Selecione a Escola
    </button>
    <table >
    <!--
</><li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Escola1</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Escola2</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Escola3</a></li>-->
    </table>
    </div>
```

////////////
Codigo C#
////////////

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using MatriculaEscolar.Models;

    namespace MatriculaEscolar.Pages.Alunos
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly MatriculaEscolar.Models.BancoDeDados _context;

        public CreateModel(MatriculaEscolar.Models.BancoDeDados context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Matricula Matricula { get; set; } = default!;

        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            // Converte a Data da matricula para Utc
            MatriculaEscolar.DataMatricula = MatriculaEscolar.DataMatricula.ToUniversalTime();
           
            

            _context.Alunos.Add(MatriculaEscolar);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Deixei uma orientação [na primeira pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/592767/70) que fez sobre o assunto. Em vez de repostar, o ideal é editar aquela. Automaticamente isto faz com que ela entre em revisão. Para evitar duplicação de orientações, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas na original continua disponível.